# Do I need to unsubscribe Click event to prevent memory leaks?

Tags: c#, android, memory-leaks, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am learning Xamarin Android, and I see a lot of official samples using lambdas to subscribe Click events. Something like: `mButton.Click += (sender, args) => { ... }` is very common. I think this pattern, using lambda, cannot unsubscribe the event.(Correct me if I am wrong :) )

Today I read this document: [Cross-Platform Performance - Unsubscribe from Events](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/#events). It says that we should unsubscribe events to prevent memory leaks.

Then I am confused. Should I unsubscribe all the Click events? I feel that since the mButton is a member of my Activity, when destroying my Activity, the mButton should also be destroyed and therefore it is not necessary to unsubscribe its Click event. Is is true? If so, then in what cases should I unsubscribe a event?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try using Rx works like charm with events, you may find a lot of memory leaks are gone when you switch to this model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it depends. As long there there are no references kept and the garbage collector can do his job, you don't have to. But otherwise it is good practice to do so to prevent memory leaks. So I prefer doing this.

To unsibscribe lambda events, just store it in a variable or field

```
EventHandler buttonOnClick = (sender, args) => button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);
button.Click += buttonOnClick;
button.Click -= buttonOnClick;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I generally do it

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.LoginPage);

        InflateViews ();

    }

    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume ();

        BindHandlers ();
    }

    protected override void OnPause ()
    {
        base.OnPause ();

        UnBindHandlers ();
    }

    void InflateViews()
    {
        loginButton = FindViewById (Resource.Id.loginButton);
        usernameField = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.userName);
        passwordField = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.password);
        forgotPassword = FindViewById (Resource.Id.forgotPassword);
    }

    void BindHandlers()
    {
        loginButton.Click+= LoginButton_Click;
        forgotPassword.Click+= ForgotPassword_Click;
    }

    void ForgotPassword_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartActivity (typeof(ForgotPasswordActivity));
    }

    void UnBindHandlers()
    {
        loginButton.Click-= LoginButton_Click;
        forgotPassword.Click-= ForgotPassword_Click;
    }
```

Comment: Looks great ! I am thinking about implementing something like this. One follow up question. Why BindHandlers() & UnBindHandlers() in OnResume() & OnPause, not in OnCreate() & OnStop? Thanks!

Comment: OnStop needn't be callled asap an Activity is destroyed or a new activity is launched.  So there are chances that OnCreate is called but OnStop is not called.  But onresume /onpause is a pair that is just awesome.  OnPause will surely be called as the user leaves the Activity

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely yes!

To prevent memory leaks it is important to prevent cycling references and such. Take your time and search on SO and you will find a lot about this topic.